# JavaFX NoClassDefFoundError: Stage

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make my first JavaFX code for an assignment and I keep getting this error

`Error: Unable to initialize main class application.Main`

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Stage`

I am only trying to run the test code that comes with JavaFX. I have installed multiple JavaFX SDKs now. I am also using eclipse. I am stumped.

Comment: What IDE do you use?  In Eclipse try clicking `Project` => `Clean`, might help things.  Other IDE's I assume have a similar option.

Comment: Maybe you are using JDK > 8?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].